# I am not getting webservice request sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have installed JMeter 3 in Linux. I am not getting all the samplers. Many samplers including web service request sampler is missing. How can I include this? Is it my fault or system's?

Comment: You should explore a little bit before posting questions... Start [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) and use Google!

Answer (score 2):

The latest JMeter version where you can find `WebService(SOAP) Request` is **Apache JMeter 2.9**. If you need to open an older test plan i.e. to convert it to newer test format you can get JMeter 2.9 from [JMeter download archives area](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/)

For the moment it is recommended to use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for both SOAP and REST web services testing. You can specify the necessary headers, i.e. `Content-Type` or `SOAPAction` via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

References:

- [Building a WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html)
- [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)